# Time in HHMM format

Tags: java, date

I want to use time as a HHMM format, like in the military's 1600 hrs for 4 PM. I was curious: Is there a way of getting it so by some dateformatter?

Feel free to recommend any third-party library or pure Java API solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the [java.text.SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm");
System.out.println(format.format(date));
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 4):

## `LocalTime`

Current time using *java.time.LocalTime* and formatting using *java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter* ( java 8)

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.now();
String t = time.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
System.out.println(t);

//output
05:41
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm").format(new Date()));
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 and later, use [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

```
LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmm");
```

Comment: Basically correct, but more appropriate to use `LocalTime` rather than `LocalDateTime`. Also, I suggest always specifying the optional `ZoneId` argument when calling `now()`, rather than relying implicitly on the JVM’s current default time zone which can be changed at any moment by any code in any app running within than JVM.

Comment: Tip: For before Java 8, use the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project where much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 and Java 7. For Android, see *ThreeTenABP* project.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use Joda-Time http://www.joda.org/joda-time/userguide.html

It  provides a quality replacement for the Java date and time classes.

```
   DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
   String hhmm=dateTime.toString("hhmm"));
```

Comment: a precise solution would be better

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: That formatting pattern should be uppercase `H`: `HHmm` for 24-hour clock as requested by the Question. `hhmm` is for 12-hour clock.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Apache Commons Lang [FastDateFormat](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/FastDateFormat.html) and [DateFormatUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateFormatUtils.html) for formatting dates and times.  `FastDateFormat` is a drop in replacement for `SimpleDateFormat` that is fast and thread safe and `DateFormatUtils` is great for formatting ISO8601 dates and times.