# Time setting HHmm

Tags: xcode, time, nsdateformatter

I am building complex [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) applications, and I've been asked to have a start time, and stop time fields, calculate to a decimal field.

Now the time must be in 24 hour format and only be in HHmm format, not HH:mm!

When the number is in the field start/stop have a calculate from the right, counting the left two char$ would be minutes, third and fourth char$ would be hours. Then covert to decimal 0.00.

Where do I start?

Stack Overflow question *[Time in HHMM format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326619)* is for Java. What about Xcode?

Comment: What programming language? What platform? What have you tried so far? Please note that comparing Java to Xcode makes no sense. One is a programming language and the other is an IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Sample code
double duration = 2.75;
double decimal = floor(duration) - duration; // decimal = .75 (floor will round down)
double minutes = .75 * 60; // 60 minutes per hour, multiply to convert from decimal to minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HHmm"];
NSString *timeString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: Thank you, but this gives me the current time in HHmm, if the user types in 1200 start 1300 end the end result needs to be 1.0

Comment: I given you an example in Xcode, [NSDate date] cam be replaced with [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:yourTimeInterval]

Answer (score 0):

**Time to decimal**

Enter in numbers to a reference time, but not time as you think in 24 hour or more to a decimal number. The only calculations done are splitting a string of numbers in to two strings, and calculate start and stop in a decimal format.

```
    // Strings converted to integers, and float integers back into strings.
    // Time entered in is ONLY 24 hour with 00,15,30,45 minutes.

    @synthesize labelTotal;
    @synthesize labelStart;
    @synthesize labelStop;
    @synthesize remarkLabel;

    NSString *START = [self.startTextField text];
    NSString *END = [self.stopTextField text];
    remarkLabel.text = @"";

    //Take START convert to Decimal
    NSLog(@"startString: %@", START);

    //Convert nsstring (24 Hour) to decimal
    int a = [self.startTextField.text intValue];

    int startHH = a / 100;
    int startmm = a % 100;

    NSLog(@"startHH: %d", startHH);
    NSLog(@"startmm: %d", startmm);

    //Define startmm
    if (startmm == 15)
    {
        NSInteger mmTime = 25;
        NSLog(@"Start Hour is: %d", startHH);
        NSLog(@"Start Minutes is: %ld", (long)mmTime);

        //Combine startHH.mmTime

        NSString *newStart1a = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", startHH];
        NSString *newStart1b = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)mmTime];
        NSString *recStart1a = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", newStart1a, newStart1b];

        NSLog(@"Decimal Start Time is: %@", recStart1a);
        labelStart.text = recStart1a;
    }
    else
        if (startmm == 30)
        {
            int mmTime = 50;
            NSLog(@"Minutes is: %ld", (long)mmTime);
            //Combine startHH.mmTime

            NSString *newStart1d = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", startHH];
            NSString *newStart1e = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)mmTime];
            NSString *recStart1b = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", newStart1d, newStart1e];

            NSLog(@"Decimal Start Time is: %@", recStart1b);
            labelStart.text = recStart1b;
        }
        else
            if (startmm == 45)
            {
                int mmTime = 75;
                NSLog(@"Minutes is: %ld", (long)mmTime);
                //Combine startHH.mmTime

                NSString *newStart1g = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", startHH];
                NSString *newStart1h = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)mmTime];
                NSString *recStart1c = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", newStart1g, newStart1h];

                NSLog(@"Decimal Start Time is: %@", recStart1c);
                labelStart.text = recStart1c;
            }
            else
                if (startmm == 00)
                {
                    NSString *newStart1g = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", startHH];
                    NSString *recStart1c = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.00", newStart1g];

                    NSLog(@"Decimal Start Time is: %@", recStart1c);
                    labelStart.text = recStart1c;
                }

    //Take END convert to Decimal
    NSLog(@"stopString: %@", END);

    int b = [self.stopTextField.text intValue];
    int stopHH = b / 100;
    int stopmm = b % 100;

    NSLog(@"stopHH: %d", stopHH);
    NSLog(@"stopmm: %d", stopmm);

    //Define stopmm
    if (stopmm == 15)
    {
        NSInteger mmTime = 25;
        NSLog(@"Start Hour is: %d", stopHH);
        NSLog(@"Start Minutes is: %ld", (long)mmTime);

        //Combine startHH.mmTime
        NSString *newStop1a = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", stopHH];
        NSString *newStop1b = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)mmTime];
        NSString *recStop1a = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", newStop1a, newStop1b];

        NSLog(@"Decimal Start Time is: %@", recStop1a);
        labelStop.text = recStop1a;
    }
    else
        if (stopmm == 30)
        { int mmTime = 50;
            NSLog(@"Minutes is: %ld", (long)mmTime);
            //Combine startHH.mmTime

            NSString *newStop1d = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", stopHH];
            NSString *newStop1e = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)mmTime];
            NSString *recStop1b = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", newStop1d, newStop1e];

            NSLog(@"Decimal Start Time is: %@", recStop1b);
            labelStop.text = recStop1b;
        }

        else if (stopmm == 45)
        {
            int mmTime = 75;
            NSLog(@"Minutes is: %ld", (long)mmTime);

            //Combine startHH.mmTime
            NSString *newStop1g = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", stopHH];
            NSString *newStop1h = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)mmTime];
            NSString *recStop1c = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", newStop1g, newStop1h];

            NSLog(@"Decimal Start Time is: %@", recStop1c);
            labelStop.text = recStop1c;
        }
        else
            if (stopmm == 00)
            {
                NSString *newStop1g = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", stopHH];
                NSString *recStop1c = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.00", newStop1g];

                NSLog(@"Decimal Start Time is: %@", recStop1c);
                labelStop.text = recStop1c;
            }

    //Convert back into decimal
    float start1 = [self.labelStart.text floatValue];
    float stop1 = [self.labelStop.text floatValue];

    NSLog(@"Start Start: %f", start1);
    NSLog(@"Stop Stop: %f", stop1);

    //Subtact END from START in Decimal
    float c = stop1 - start1;

    //Show TOTAL in Decimal
    NSString *total1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", c];

    if ([total1 isEqual:@"0"])
    {
        labelTotal.text = @"";
        NSLog(@"BLANK");
    }
    else
    {
        labelTotal.text = total1;
        NSLog(@"Total: %@", total1);
    }

    //You can add additional if statements below for more conditions needed
}
```

Comment: Please do not include a "copyright notice" on your posts. When you submit a post here, it is licensed as noted here: [What is the license for the content I post?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing)

Comment: He might not be allowed to post it here, if it cannot be licensed by the CC license. But you are not allowed to remove copyright notices of code you do not own. If you do anything at all, you must remove the code, not the copyright notice. Now you did a copyright infringement.